# Strip unwanted characters from a series of text files

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

Hi I've got a list of csv files which need to be formatted properly by getting rid of some unwanted characters.

original:

```
9: ["2019-4-24",-7.101458109105941]
10: ["2019-5-6",-7.050609022950812]
100: ["2019-5-6",-7.050609022950812]
```

I'd like to modify as:

```
2019-4-24,-7.101458109105941
2019-5-6,-7.050609022950812
2019-5-6,-7.050609022950812
```

There are dozens of files in this format and I was thinking of writing a sed command which makes a series of null substitutions for all the files in directory, but these don't seem to work.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/^[[:space:]]*//" {} \; 
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/\[//" {} \; 
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/\]//" {} \;
```

Many thanks for suggestions.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?

Comment: Hi Andy.  To clarify, my commands ran, but without error messages and there was no change to the original files.

Comment: What if you just run the sed command on one file, without using `find` to find them? We need to know if it is `sed` not changing them, or `find` not finding them.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work on my linux machine.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/^.\+\[//;s/\"//g;s/\]//" {} \;
```

Which, from what I gather is equivalent to the following in macOS:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' "s/^.\+\[//;s/\"//g;s/\]//" {} \;
```

It comprises of 3 substitutions(separated by semicolon):

`s/^.\+\[//` deletes everything from the start to the "[" character.

`s/\"//g` deletes all occurences of the double quote character.

`s/\]//` deletes the final "]" at the end.

And please make a backup or something if you are going to use `sed -i`.

Comment: Thank you philiptomk. This solution looks nice, but unfortunately it did not work. To be clear, if I run this at the command line and should make the substitutions in all of the files in the same directory, correct?  There seems to be no change to the files.

Comment: I don't yet see any issues in the command, You are going to have to do some trouble shooting. Does `find ./ -type f` list all the files which you wish to change? If so, try running a simple command under `-exec` like `find ./ -type f -exec file {} \;`. Also try running the sed command on a single copy of a file to see if that works for you. Errors and output will make the troubleshooting easier.

Comment: So strange.  I run something like `sed -i "" "s/^.\+\[//;s/\"//g;s/\]//" "myfile.csv"` which executes without error, but the file remains unchanged.

Comment: I suspect that even on macos, you do not need to put quotes around the fileneame.